# pg_connect fatal error using php

Tags: php, .htaccess, postgresql

I have a Postgres 9.1 database running on a remote server. I am trying to help a programmer set up remote posting to a table using php on my hostgator account.

I have modified the pg_hba.conf file on my postgres server to allow all connections from the ip address of my hostgator server using a password.

On hostgator, I am using a linux account and have modified the php.ini file to enable the line:

extension=php_pgsql.so

I have also tried this line:

extension=php_pgsql.dll

both with the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /home1/kipsoft/public_html/hfs_forms/connection.php on line 6

In order to enable the php.ini file for every domain, I did modify the .htaccess file as in the instructions:

```
# Use PHP55 as default
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
# BEGIN custom php.ini PHP55
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home1/kipsoft
</IfModule>
# END custom php.ini
```

The connect script looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
//$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '209.239.000.001');
//$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypassword', 'myforms');

$db_connection = pg_connect("host=209.239.000.001 port=5432 dbname=myforms user=myuser password=mypassword");

/*if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}*/

ini_set("memory_limit", "192M");
?>
```

Unfortunately, I know nothing about php and I think the programmer has no experience with postgres. Anything to help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does phpinfo show? Did you install the postgresql-extension on the webserver? http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Is php5-pgsql installed on your linux machine? Which distrubution are you using?

Comment: I installed php 5.5 on the hostgator server which is running linux. I will run phpinfo and see what that says.

Comment: phpinfo is showing PHP Version 5.4.38. I need to check on that. And I cannot see anything about pgsql.

Comment: OK. I was able to upgrade php to PHP Version 5.5.22. I will try to enable pg in the php.ini file.

Comment: I tried modifying the php.ini file in hostgator to include extension=pgsql.so or extension=php_pgsql.dll or extension=php_pgsql.so but I can't anything in the phpinfo which shows anything related to pgsql.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Linux CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Answer (score 0):

Check if php-pgsql is installed. Run:

```
php –me
```

or

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

If you don't see pgsql installed install it by running as root:

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

Enable pgsql in php.ini - uncomment this line - note, that dll is for Windows only:

```
extension=php_pgsql.so
```

Restart apache:

```
service httpd restart
```

Check if php-pgsql is working now.

Comment: From hostgator: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/php-modules   does this mean I am out-of-luck?

Comment: I have looked at your link - it seems that you cannot use pgsql. But there is possibility to contact support about php modules.

Comment: Ok. I just found out that it is not possible to install the pgsql module in the hosting plan that I currently have, and that I would have to move to a vps in order to activate that.